# protractor and oi.select options click

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

This is my template html for oi.select.

```
<oi-select class="oi-select" 
    oi-options="group.name for group in groups track by group._id" 
    multiple placeholder="" ng-model="selectedGroups">
</oi-select>
```

I tried the following code in test.js

```
element(by.model('selectedGroups')).click().then(function () {
    element.all(by.repeater("(group, options) in groups"))
       .then(function (guests) {
           guests[0].click();
       });
});
```

It only clicks one options. `guests[0].getText()` gives all group names labels. Please if you solve it before, help me. I tried many examples of select but there is no oi.select specific I found. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question what you have, because if I look at https://tamtakoe.github.io/oi.select/ and create an example test I'm able to open the select and select an option.

Comment: do you want to click all available options?

Comment: @wswebcreation Yes, I can only select one option. It's like random.

Comment: @PaulCo It'll be good if I can select like the first two options, etc.

Comment: But what is the question then? And how should it work according to you?

Comment: I want to select a specific option. Maybe by value or index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code when selecting by index or by value/string.
The index/values that will be selected are inside an array.
So that user can select multiple values.

```
describe('test', function() {
    var arrIndex = [2, 0];
    var arrString = ['jeans', 'belt'];
    var elmModel = element(by.model('query'));

    it('open browser', function() {      
        browser.get('https://tamtakoe.github.io/oi.select/#/select/#multiple');
    });

    it('test index', function() {      
        browser.get('https://tamtakoe.github.io/oi.select/#/select/#multiple');
        var elmRptr = element.all(by.repeater('option in options'))
        selectByIndex(0, arrIndex, elmRptr);
    });

    it('test string', function() {      
        selectByString(0, arrString);
    });

    function selectByString(i, arrTemp) {
        if (i < arrTemp.length) {
            elmModel.click();  
            var elmString = element(by.cssContainingText('[ng-repeat="option in options"]', arrTemp[i]));
            elmString.click();
            selectByString(i + 1, arrTemp);
        }
    }

    function selectByIndex(i, arrTemp, elmTemp) {
        if (i < arrTemp.length) {
            elmModel.click();  
            elmTemp.get(arrTemp[i]).click();
            selectByIndex(i + 1, arrTemp, elmTemp);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's amazing. It works in my project well.